# TableView background Image in iPad Application

Tags: ipad, uitableview

I have following code which works fine in iPhone application but in iPad I always get grey/light blue background colour. Even if I change background colour it does not take effect.

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg1024x768.png"]]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the magic:

```
if ( [self.myTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundView)] )
    self.myTableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Also, use UIViewController with a UITableView, not UITableViewController, and place your background image in a UIImageView placed under the UITableView.

Comment: Thanks Bogatyr. I'm gonna give it a go. Will let you know.

Comment: p.s. I had exactly the same problem, it was infuriating.  The issue was the addition of the backgroundView property in OS3.2 (the ipad's first release).

Comment: Hi Bogatyr, I have tried that and now I am getting white background. In my nib file I have UIView. And under that I have imageview (background image) and tableview. Image is placed under tableview. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you set the background color of the tableview to clearcolor?   Are you doing it in the right place (viewDidLoad is a good place)?

Comment: Yes I placed it in ViewDidLoad. I got no clue. Any idea?

Comment: Great! Bogatyr. Sorry I forgot to set proper background image for the imageView. It's working great now. Really thanks for that.

Comment: Can someone explain why the difference between iPad/iPhone with UITableView (both running 4.3)?